# R predict.cox function type expected

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am using cox model for prediction.

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + ph.ecog + strata(inst), lung)
predict(fit,type="expected")
```

In the predict.coxph doc, it says type expected is 'the expected number of events given the covariates and follow-up time'. What is the follow-up time means here? How can I change it?

Comment: In the case presented with no newdata argument, the followup time is simply the `time` variable.

Comment: Thanks, if I want to predict for new data how can I change the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of the "expected" for one particular set of patient features with a single time chosen to be greater than the mean survival time for this cohort, but using all the unique institution codes for the 'lung' dataset.

```
 (pr.fit.new <- predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(age=50, time=365, status=0, 
                                ph.ecog=2,inst=unique(lung$inst[!is.na(lung$inst)]) ),
                        type="expected"))
 [1] 1.1886094 1.7679429 1.6651195 1.3117278 0.7743925 0.8501810
 [7] 1.9686954 1.2560981 2.5845069 0.6513932 1.1241870 1.1515346
[13] 1.1616482 1.9071766 4.2468797 0.4921904 0.5875339 0.5647238
```

The strata have remarkably different "baseline hazards" which produces material differences in the "expected" for hypothetical persons with the same covariate and period of observation.